# How to check if listView column contain more then one item?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sorting, listview

I want to make that when i click on a listView column it will sort it.
In this case i have 3 columns in the constructor:

```
ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.View = View.Details;
            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.SuspendLayout();
            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.LabelEdit = true;
            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Columns.Add("From", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Columns.Add("Subject", 200);
            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Columns.Add("Date", 300);
            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Sorting = SortOrder.None;
            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.SelectedIndexChanged += lvnf_SelectedIndexChanged;
            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Click += lvnf_Click;
            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.MouseDown += lvnf_MouseDown;
            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.ColumnClick += lvnf_ColumnClick;
```

"From"
"Subject"
"Date"

So i want when i click on the top of one of the columns to sort it depending on the column name From,Subject,Date the first two From and Subject i'm not sure what kind of sorting can be done with it but how can i sort the Date column ?

```
void lvnf_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Column.
                ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer(e.Column);
        }
```

I started to make if (e.Column.
I tried to check first if the column any of them contain more then one item if not there is no reason to sort anyway.

Second i'm not sure if the line:

```
ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer(e.Column);
```

Is any good ?

What i tried now is this code in the click event:

```
void lvnf_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewSorter Sorter = new ListViewSorter();
            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.ListViewItemSorter = Sorter;
            if (!(ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.ListViewItemSorter is ListViewSorter))
                return;
            Sorter = (ListViewSorter)ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.ListViewItemSorter;

            if (Sorter.LastSort == e.Column)
            {
                if (ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Sorting == SortOrder.Ascending)
                    ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending;
                else
                    ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
            }
            else
            {
                ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending;
            }
            Sorter.ByColumn = e.Column;

            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Sort();
        }
```

And the class ListViewSorter

```
public class ListViewSorter : System.Collections.IComparer
        {
            public int Compare(object o1, object o2)
            {
                if (!(o1 is ListViewItem))
                    return (0);
                if (!(o2 is ListViewItem))
                    return (0);

                ListViewItem lvi1 = (ListViewItem)o2;
                string str1 = lvi1.SubItems[ByColumn].Text;
                ListViewItem lvi2 = (ListViewItem)o1;
                string str2 = lvi2.SubItems[ByColumn].Text;

                int result;
                if (lvi1.ListView.Sorting == SortOrder.Ascending)
                    result = String.Compare(str1, str2);
                else
                    result = String.Compare(str2, str1);

                LastSort = ByColumn;

                return (result);
            }


            public int ByColumn
            {
                get { return Column; }
                set { Column = value; }
            }
            int Column = 0;

            public int LastSort
            {
                get { return LastColumn; }
                set { LastColumn = value; }
            }
            int LastColumn = 0;
        }
```

The problem now is i can click on the first column each time to sort it but on the other two columns i can click only once each time. In my logic i should be able to click on each column all the time to sort it no ? For example in the Date column if i click once and then once again it should sort it by newest to oldest dates but i can click on the date column only if first i clicked on other column.

Comment: Not sure I understand. why would you create an extra case? when sorting works with many or few items, why care? And could you please capitalze your 'i's? And add `ListView` and `Sort` to the tags. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That line of code should work fine. As for checking if the column has content, that is fairly unnecessary. Since you have 3 columns and presumably always will, sorting by a column with no data would still be a valid option to sort by. Though it would simply sort it to its present state. If the column exists it already has some form of data in reference to the use of the list, even if that data contains a null at the moment.

If you do have columns that are used that continue not to have data I'd suggest looking into doing a dynamic list view where you generate columns when they are needed, to see if it might better suit your program.

**ListViewCostumControl is misspelled